# How to do task parallelization having some for loops in c using openmp?

Tags: c, openmp

I have a c program as below:

```
int a[10];
int b;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)

     function1(a[i]);
function1(b);
```

Now I want to parallelize all these 11 calls of function function1(). How can I do this using openmp?

I have tried

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
#pragma omp section
#pragmal omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     function1(a[i]);
#pragma omp section
function1(b);
}
```

But the above code doesn't seem to work.
EDIT: Please read function1(b) as some different function, ie function2(b).

Comment: You could at least show us what you tried and how it failed :)

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth, Thanks, I have added my efforts in the question.

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean? What happens/does not happen? How are you compiling the code?

Comment: @Mat , I have used g++ main.c -fopenmp to compile the code. I am not getting any improvement in performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way, that doesn't depend on OpemMP, is to add `b` to the `a` array.
This way, you have a single loop to parallelize.
Just make `a` 11 ints long, and put the value of `b` in the last one.

In a more general case (assuming the members of `a` are not integers, but something larger), you may want to change `function1` to get a pointer. Then build another array, of 11 pointers. Set 10 to point to cells of `a`, the last to `b`.

In an even more general case, the function called for `b` is a different one (possibly with entirely different parameters). In this case, you can still use one loop:

```
for (i=0; i<11; i++) {
    if (i<10) {
        function1(a[i]);
    } else {
        function2(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, It is my bad that I have not fully mentioned my environment. Actually second function is some different function( say function2). In this case I cannot use the above recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is using the `parallel for` pragma:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    function1(a[i]);
```

Remember that you must turn on the appropiate switch for your compiler to enable OMP support. In GCC, for example, that switch is `-fopenmp`

Comment: thank, but I also want to parallelize the function call function1(b)

Comment: @quartz: you can't "parallelize" a single call. You'll need to split that function into parallelizable chunks.

Comment: Is that last call to `function1` really worth to parallelize? In that case, why not moving the parallelism to inside that function?

Comment: @Win32, actually the last call of function is not same as function1, it is function2(b). I should have mentioned that in question before.